# How can I spec before_filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to spec my controllers before_filter with rspec.
I thought to use ActionController::Testing::ClassMethods#before_filters for it.

I got these results in my rails c:

```
2.0.0p353 :006 > ActionController::Base.singleton_class.send :include, ActionController::Testing::ClassMethods
2.0.0p353 :003 > EquipmentController.before_filters
```

=> [:process_action, :process_action]

But in reality this is the filter on my action:

```
class EquipmentController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the test that you're trying to write, and why do you feel you need to write it? If you're trying to test that the EquipmentController's `before_filters` contain `authenticate_user!`, that's mostly just checking that you haven't forgotten to type that code in. If you're testing that the method `authenticate_user!` is called before the code in your controllers, then you're testing that Rails is doing its job, and rails already has tests for that. IMO, you should test the *behavior*, i.e. that authenticated users can do whatever the actions do and non-authenticated users can't.

Comment: It is not just checking that I type that code because I want it automatically by tests... I am not testing the authenticate_user! method.

Comment: Have you tried triggering an action in the EquipmentController in your spec? You can probably do it like so: `get :index` if you have an index action

Comment: That is my old way.. I am looking for something more effective which checs only the declaration of the beforefilter...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I did in my project:

```
# spec/support/matchers/have_filters.rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_filters do |kind, *names|
  match do |controller|
    filters = controller._process_action_callbacks.select{ |f| f.kind == kind }.map(&:filter)
    names.all?{ |name| filters.include?(name) }
  end
end

# spec/support/controller_macros.rb
module ControllerMacros
  def has_before_filters *names
    expect(controller).to have_filters(:before, *names)
  end
end

# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ControllerMacros, type: :controller
end
```

and then you can just use it in controller specs like:

```
# spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe ApplicationController do
  describe 'class' do
    it { has_before_filters(:authenticate_user) }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the approach I am looking for... I think I will boost our code to match my DSL... Or I will massage my DSL to support :except and :only.

Comment: Kopinski I evolved my solution based on mine and yours... you can give my answer a point and my question too if you want... ;)

Answer (score 7):

I figured out a way based on the source code from the [ActionController::Testing::ClassMethods#before_filter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f2cd3e9fee721d7485bb1c1b4151612d733da3a/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb)

This will be my spec:

```
describe EquipmentController do
  context 'authentication' do
    specify{ expect(EquipmentController).to filter(:before, with: :authenticate_user!, only: :index)}
  end
...
```

This is my matcher in spec/support/matchers/filter.rb

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :filter do |kind, filter|
  match do |controller|
    extra = -> (x) {true}
    if filter[:except].present?
      extra = -> (x) { x.options[:unless].include?( "action_name == '#{filter[:except]}'") }
    elsif filter[:only].present?
      extra = -> (x) { x.options[:if].include?( "action_name == '#{filter[:only]}'") }
    end
    controller._process_action_callbacks.find{|x|x.kind == kind && x.filter == filter[:with] && extra.call(x)}
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using this solution for 2 month now with great success So I advise this genric solution for everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I'm not clear on what you want to test, exactly. It sounds like you're testing for the existence of

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

but this is only helpful if you also know that `:authenticate_user!` behaves as you intend. So I would recommend a two-pronged testing attack -

1. Test that #authenticate_user! behaves according to your specifications
2. Write specs to ensure the method you are protecting with the before_filter has correct behavior when the user is logged in and logged out.

Idiomatically, `before_filter` methods are declared *private*, so your specs could look something like:

```
describe ApplicationController do
    describe 'GET /my_account' do # a method to which the before_filter applies
        subject { get :my_account }

        context 'with a logged-out session' do
            it 'redirects to the homepage' do
                response.should redirect_to root_url
            end
        end

        context 'with a logged-in session' do
            # if you use FactoryGirl and have a spec helper method log_in() to set up the session
            before { log_in(FactoryGirl.create :user) }
            it { should render_template('my_account') } # etc...
        end
    end

    describe 'private #authenticate_user!' do
        subject { ApplicationController.send(:authenticate_user!) }

        it 'calls the authentication logic' do
            Authentication.expects(:attempt_login) # or whatever to verify the internals
            subject
        end
    end
end
```

By testing both separately, you can verify that the desired behavior is maintained regardless of the implementation of `:authenticate_user!` or other login internals. And, you get to do it without doing too much reliance on Rails internals!

Let me know if this makes any sense whatsoever. I'm relatively new to StackOverflow, so feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You spoted right. I want to test for the existence of before_filter... And I know what the authenticate_user! does so I don't want to test that.

Comment: Ah, okay. Come to think of it, my `authenticate_user!` specs won't work anyway because controllers have to be instantiated correctly in order for calling their methods to make any sense. But I stand by the first idea, which is to test the behavior of the framework you're using. You shouldn't "test the framework" (devise) but testing what happens when the user isn't logged in is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem provides you with `use_after_action`, `use_around_action` and `use_before_action`, which are simple callback tests. No need to write your custom matchers.

Comment: it's actually very similar. Maybe they got their inspiration from this question

Comment: yes, that could happen easily :)

I am a huge fan of should-matchers. I should have added myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1. Is `authenticate_user!` a method you wrote yourself or is it a method that comes with a gem like Rails or Devise? If that method is not written by you, you don't need to write a test for it. Only test code that you wrote yourself. The gem's authors have already written tests for their code.
2. If you want to test that the method `authenticate_user!` is being called in a controller, you can do `controller.should_receive(:authenticate_user!)` in your spec to check that it's being called.
3. You could also check if EquipmentController calls before_filter by writing a spec like this:

`EquipmentController.should_receive(:before_filter).with(:authenticate_user!)`

Comment: ...expected 1 times, received 0 times..., try it please on a dummy app... :)

Comment: The should_receive is inconvenient because in case of skip_before_filter we need to follow the logic of filters... through the ancestor chain... I thought to test only the result of the filter chain...