# Verify user authenticated for actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rspec-rails

I'm using devise and want to check in my specs that certain controller actions are covered by `authenticate_user!`

I've looked over the devise docs, I feel there's something really simple and obvious I'm not getting about the way devise works.

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775737/how-can-i-spec-before-filters) I built a spec to check this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

When I run the spec, I get:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user!)

   (#<LibrariesController:0x000001035639f8>).authenticate_user!(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

**libraries_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe LibrariesController, type: :controller do

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    skip("Add a hash of attributes valid for your model")
  }

  let(:invalid_attributes) {
    skip("Add a hash of attributes invalid for your model")
  }

  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "should be authenticated" do
      get :index, {}
      expect(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user!)
    end
  end
end
```

And the controller itself:

**libraries_controller.rb**

```
class LibrariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_library, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /libraries
  # GET /libraries.json
  def index
    @libraries = Library.all
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_library
      @library = Library.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was embarassing. Turns out I had the expectation and method call in the wrong order in my spec. It should've been:

```
describe "GET #index" do
  it "should be authenticated" do
    expect(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user!)
    get :index, {}
  end
end
```