# fail to rspec before_filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to Rails and I am using [Boti's evolved way to test my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775737/how-can-i-spec-before-filters), however I got the following error:

```
> Failures:

  1) ApplicationController UploadsController admin_only should filter :before and {:with=>:admin_only, :except=>:show}
     Failure/Error: extra = -> (x) { x.options[:unless].include?( "action_name == '#{filter[:except]}'") }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `options' for #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x000006060f6598>
     # ./spec/support/matchers/filter.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/matchers/filter.rb:9:in `call'
     # ./spec/support/matchers/filter.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/matchers/filter.rb:9:in `find'
     # ./spec/support/matchers/filter.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Could anyone help me out of this, thanks.

***This is my spec:***

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
       describe UploadsController do
        context 'authentication' do
         specify{ expect(UploadsController).to filter(:before, with: :authenticate_user!)}
        end
        context 'admin_only' do
         specify{ expect(UploadsController).to filter(:before, with: :admin_only, except: :index)}
        end
      end
   end
```

***This is controller***

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :admin_only, :except => :index
   def index
    begin
      @uploads = Upload.all
    rescue
      redirect_to uploads_alert_uploads_path(:error_path => request.url, :error_time => DateTime.now)
    end
  end
end
```

***This is matcher in spec/support/matchers/filter.rb***

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :filter do |kind, filter|
  match do |controller|
    extra = -> (x) {true}
    if filter[:except].present?
      extra = -> (x) { x.options[:unless].include?( "action_name == '#{filter[:except]}'") }
    elsif filter[:only].present?
      extra = -> (x) { x.options[:if].include?( "action_name == '#{filter[:only]}'") }
    end
    controller._process_action_callbacks.find{|x|x.kind == kind && x.filter == filter[:with] && extra.call(x)}
  end
end
```

Comment: please post relevant portions of your spec and your controller code.

Comment: Yes, I have added them to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A better test would be to assert that a user cannot access the UploadsController (requests returns 404) and that an admin can (request returns 200).

Asserting that the filter is called ties your test to the implementation of the `admin_only` method and not the end result of limiting what a user can access.

Comment: Thanks Joey, I agree with you. I have completed that kind test by using anonymous controller.